# c++ check if array equals array not made

Tags: c++, arrays

Ddoes any body know how do do this? Thanks if you do. I am new in c++. I don't know what do do. Python is much better in my opinion.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    if (nums == [1, 2, 3, 4]){
        cout<<1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` as it's highly non-portable. Also avoid `using namespace std` as the `std::` prefix serves an important purpose.

Comment: Is `==` a situation where arrays decay to pointers? I know you can't compare raw arrays using `==`, but I'm not sure what exact mechanism actually is occurring under the hood.

Comment: That code won't even compile.   `[1,2,3,4]` is not a valid syntax for expressing an array in C++.   In any event, raw arrays like `nums` cannot be compared directly, because they decay to pointers, so comparing them `array1 == array2` only tests if their first element has the same address.    Either write a loop that compares elements one at a time, or use a standard container (`std::array<int, 4>`, `std::vector<int>`, etc) to hold the elements.   Those containers are part of the standard library, and do support being compared as you wish.

Comment: And, if you think Python is better, then use Python, rather than complaining that C++ does not do things like Python.   C++ and Python are different languages, with different purposes.   And each does some things better than the other.

Comment: And neither can make a decent burger. Depending on your immediate needs that can make both Python and C++ utterly worthless.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of plain arrays to realize this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main(void) {
    std::array<int, 4> nums = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    if (nums == std::array<int, 4>{1, 2, 3, 4}){
        std::cout<<1;
    }
}
```

Also see:

- [c++ - Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [c++ - Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 0):

From C++17, you can use class template argument deduction to simplify MikeCAT's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64829391/8372853) like this:

```
std::array nums = {1, 2, 3, 4};
if (nums == std::array{1, 2, 3, 4}) {
    std::cout << 1;
}
```